# Why was my answer voted down?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

[My answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/74387/33) to [a question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/74381/how-close-to-beam-edge-can-i-put-light-fixture-nails) was down voted. I realize it is not the apocalypse, but the answer did provide assistance to the OP's question with a concern for safety. Wouldn't it have a more positive impact if when an answer that appears to be unfounded or inconsistent; that a down vote offer an explanation and reason? Even anonymously.

Comment: Looks like the answer got one down vote, and one up vote.  The down vote could have been because your answer doesn't really answer the question. The OP wants to know if the nails being so close to the edge of the joist is unsafe, and if there's any code that specifies how close to the edge of the joist nails can be placed.  Do you feel you've answered one or both of those questions?

Comment: OP's first question was answered in my first sentence . But the idea of an answer is to offer a constructive response that at the very least , as stated on "help" page for new members, "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. "   I really don't want to make an issue and take up more of your time. It's not a big deal. I was just curious and wanted to learn the rules. So thanks for the help Tester101. I see your replies and picked up some good info from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has come up many times before all over the network, most notably here:

> [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

and the consensus is that asking people to explain down-votes would be counter productive at best.

All you can do is analyse your answer with fresh eyes and see if there is anything you missed first time round.

Comment: Thanks for the response. And your last sentence is what made me post my question. A solution might be to have the person that see's a problem in an answer to highlight the specific word or words. This can be done anonymously and at the very least provide a clue as to the problem with in the answer.